# AWS Elastic Load Balancer Suggestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

I need some suggestion for creating an rendering system.

Background : I have a rendering manager which is a EC2 instance which collection image from the client and split it into number of tiles. It then forward the tiles to the rendering server which is again a EC2 instance. The rendering server is programmed in a way that, once a tile is received it starts rendering it and in the rendering duration the CPU Utilization of the server stays 100%.

Future: Now to use the elasticity of Cloud. I have created an ELB and an auto scaling group of rendering server. At this point I need suggestions, as for example, I have say 5 tiles that needed to be rendered. Hence, there will be 5 request forwarded to the rendering server via ELB. Now what would be the auto scaling policies in that case ? Desired solution is ELB just create 5 new rendering instances assign one tile to each of the instance and stop them once the task is finish.

Need suggestion on auto scaling policies, alarm configuration which suits the desired task.

Comment: I'm assuming that you need to scale the back-end (the render servers) rather than the front-end (the web servers which accept uploaded images).  I'd consider storing the images in S3 and then appending render requests (with associated image S3 URL) to SQS.  Maybe have a t1.micro controlling the render farm, launching when SQS queue depth is high.  The t1.micro controller would launch new instances (these would be spot instances beyond an initial base of on-demand instances).  The render farm would pull work items from the SQS queue and render, storing their results back into S3.

Comment: @jarmod is spot on with his recommendation, but I'd also just add that don't be so quick to turn off the instances once the work is done - if you spin one up you are going to pay for the full hour anyway, so start instances quickly (when needed), but shut them down slowly so you don't do to much many start/stops and maybe another tile comes along that could be processed on the already running instance that you already paid for the full hour.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the suggestion. You are correct I need to scale the renderer server not the manager. One additional information as you suggested S3, The rendering system is a software which rendering image based on the script which is piece of text script which the redering server understand. So there is no image as such to store in S3. I have not worked with SQS before, does it require change in the code of the system ? I want to avoid it, as in case of adding ELB I just need to replace the rendering server IP with ELB URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan, thanks for the information. It is indeed helpful. I will update the scale down policy accordingly.

Comment: @ACoder Yes, SQS is different but using it is simple.  I would seriously consider using SQS if your text scripts are below 256KB each (or use S3 + SQS if text scripts are above 256KB) as SQS can help you build a very resilient system.  You don't need a load balancer, just a farm of render nodes pulling work from an SQS queue.  If a node fails (spot instances can disappear under you), the message is automatically re-queued in the SQS queue and will be processed by another node.  You could abstract one more level and use SWF, as what you have here is actually a workflow.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the rendering system is very complex in design using Service Component Architecture concepts. Actually, the idea is, there is work-flow manager service component which is calling a rendering component on the EC2 instance behind ELB, component calling webservice. If I can get correct autoscaling than I don't have to dig into the code and change the webservice components. I would highly appreciate if you could guide any solution using ELB.I am sure, it is not tedious, but in case someone has experience then might point me to the correct direction

Comment: @ACoder OK, if you have no ability to change the rendering s/w and simply want to distribute load then set up an Auto Scaling group of instances behind an ELB and automatically scale the ASG dynamically on a sensible CloudWatch metric (for example average CPU utilization > 60%).  You may have to do some testing to determine the optimum scaling policy.

Comment: Another point in favour of SQS, You can also create auto scaling based on the number of tiles waiting for process in the queue: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-using-sqs-queue.html

Comment: @Guy Yes, I have checked SQS & found it very interesting and good option. Unfortunately, in this scenario I can not choose this option as I don't want to change the system code due to some constraint. Saying that thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I am interested in knowing the working of ELB, e.g., I will be sending just 5 request each for a tile via ELB. 1st request forwarded CPU Util. goes to 100%. For second request a new instance is created which need some time to initialize & starts processing so that its CPU Util goes to 100%. It means I have to put some artificial delay greater than the new instance starting time between two consecutive request forwarded to ELB in order to have one instance processing each tile or request. Correct me if I am wrong? Also, Is CPU Util threshold average for whole AS group or one instance?

Comment: @ACoder The ELB will distribute load across active EC2 instances.  You should run enough instances behind the ELB to cope with at least your minimum expected load.  I'd be surprised if a single instance would be pegged at 100% CPU when handling a single HTTP request (and if it did then use larger instances).  It would not be sensible to launch a new instance when a request comes in.  Instead you would configure an ASG to scale on demand (for example when average CPU utilization across all instances exceeds 75% for 15 minutes).

Comment: @ACoder I can recommend reading the AWS documentation, for example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AS_Concepts.html.